# How can I put MovieClip into 3D array?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cc

I want to create 3d array which holds movieclips and textfields. Here's my code:

```
public function init():void
{
    //initalize the arrays
    for (var _x:int = 0; _x <= MAX_X; _x++)
    {
        colArray = new Array();

        for (var _y:int = 0; _y <= MAX_Y; _y++)
        {
            textArray = new Array();

            for (var _z:int = 0; _z <= MAX_Z; _z++)
            {
                var txt:TextField = new TextField();
                textArray.push(txt);
            }
            var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
            colArray.push(mc);
        }

        rowArray.push(colArray);
    }
}

public function addBoxes(isUpdate:Boolean):void
{
    for (var _y:int = 0; _y <= MAX_Y; _y++)
    {
        for (var _x:int = 0; _x <= MAX_X; _x++)
        {
            for (var _z:int = 0; _z <= MAX_Z; _z++)
            {
                // Create captions
                var mcCaption:MovieClip = createMc("captionBox", false);
                spSource.addChild(mcCaption);
                mcCaption.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mcCaptionHandler);

                colArray[_x][_y][_z] = mcCaption;

                mcCaption.x = nextXpos;
                mcCaption.name = "beatCaption_" + _y;
                // trace(colArray[_x][_y][_z]);
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

I want some text on my movieclips. How can I do that? My code is giving me error: `TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.`

Is this statement wrong?
`colArray[_x][_y][_z] = mcCaption; // mcCaption is a movieclip`

Comment: thanks for editing the question instead of giving down vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a 3D array, because `textArray` in the innermost cycle is not pushed into `colArray` but instead you stuff a MC in there. Also, you are asking a wrong array to retrieve a 3-depth object. In your code `rowArray` is 2D array (would be 3D if you'd stuff `textArray` in there), `colArray` is a 1D array of MCs, and then you are trying to refer `colArray[_x][_y][_z]` - this one resolves to:

- colArray[_x] = empty Movieclip, created at `init()`
- colArray[_x][_y] = undefined (the MC is empty, there's no property `_y` regardless of its value
- colArray[_x][_y][_z] = runtime error, you're trying to query undefined's properties.

So, you have to check if your `init()` is correctly written, because if you need a 3D array, you are not making one right now. My guess is this:

```
public function init():void
{
    //initalize the arrays
    for (var _x:int = 0; _x <= MAX_X; _x++)
    {
        colArray = new Array();
        for (var _y:int = 0; _y <= MAX_Y; _y++)
        {
            textArray = new Array();
            for (var _z:int = 0; _z <= MAX_Z; _z++)
            {
                textArray.push(null); // placeholder
            }
            colArray.push(textArray);
        }
        rowArray.push(colArray);
    }
}
```

The `null`s pushed in the innermost loop will then be replaced if you use `rowArray[_x][_y][_z] = mcCaption;`